# Sum of values using a week range from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table like this:

sales_data

| WEEK | SALES |
| --- | --- |
| 202001 | 5 |
| 202002 | 1 |
| 202003 | 6 |
| 202006 | 3 |
| 202007 | 4 |
| 202008 | 5 |
| 202011 | 2 |
| 202012 | 3 |
| 202013 | 3 |
| 202014 | 2 |
| 202015 | 1 |
| 202017 | 1 |
| 202018 | 1 |
| 202019 | 1 |
| 202020 | 1 |

I trying to SUM the values for range of weeks, but the weeks staying in another calendar table.
I need a range from 7 weeks to do SUM.
I used the LAG Window function to generate the start week for the range. I used LAG(yearweek, 7).

| YEARWEEK | start_week |
| --- | --- |
| 202001 | null |
| 202002 | null |
| 202003 | null |
| 202004 | null |
| 202005 | null |
| 202006 | null |
| 202007 | null |
| 202008 | 202001 |
| 202009 | 202002 |
| 202010 | 202003 |
| 202011 | 202004 |
| 202012 | 202005 |
| 202013 | 202006 |
| 202014 | 202007 |
| 202015 | 202008 |

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.SALES)
FROM sales_data t1
LEFT JOIN
calendar t2
 ON t1.week BETWEEN t2.start_week AND t2.YEARWEEK
GROUP BY 
  t2.YEARWEEK
```

...but this not work.

Could somebody help me with some idea?

Comment: What is the issue with your query?  What does `start_week = NULL` mean?

Comment: The LAG function used write values after the 7th position in this column. Before the 7th position I don't have values for start_week. I'm inresting only for lines in this table when have the 2 columns with values.

Answer (score 3):

Is the issue the `NULL` handling?

```
SELECT c.YEARWEEK, SUM(t1.SALES)
FROM calendar c LEFT JOIN
     sales_data sd
     ON (sd.week >= c.start_week OR c.start_week IS NULL) AND
        sd.week <= c.YEARWEEK 
GROUP BY c.YEARWEEK
ORDER BY c.YEARWEEK;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon! Your answer got the bullseye! Thanks a lot!